# Getting error when setting the whole Ngrx store state to undefined using `Meta Reducers` by help of dispatching logout action

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx

I want to logout from my app and before logging out I want to make sure I have completely cleared my app ngrx store states using `MetaReducer` with the help of this code

```
import { StoreModule, ActionReducer, MetaReducer } from '@ngrx/store';

    export function logout(reducer: ActionReducer<any>): ActionReducer<any> {
      return function (state, action) {
        if (action.type === 'LOGOUT') {
          state = undefined;
        }

        return reducer(state, action);
      };
    }

    export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<any>[] = [logout];
```

when I am inside of a component which is subscribed to one of ngrx store state for example list of invoices, so when I am clicking log out button from here so getting this error in the console [image]

and the line which gives me the error is

```
 this.$invoice.takeWhile(() => this.isComponentAlive).subscribe(
      invoice => {

        this.permission = this.departmentService.getPermissionOfInvoiceCurrentDepartment(invoice.currentDepartmentId);

      }
    );
```

if I am changing the code to this

```
 this.$invoice.takeWhile(() => this.isComponentAlive).subscribe(
      invoice => {

        if (invoice) {
          this.permission = this.departmentService.getPermissionOfInvoiceCurrentDepartment(invoice.currentDepartmentId);
        }

      }
    );
```

it solves the problem but I have many places like this so I want to one-stop-shop solution for this anyone could help me with this.

Comment: What exactly does your logout button do? Does it dispatch a logout action that you use to navigate to a "login page" or a "you have logged out page" or how come you're still accessing the state?

Comment: @Toby my logout button calls a method which looks like this `onLogOut() {
    this.store.dispatch(new Logout());
    localStorage.clear();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }` mainly doing 3 things one dispatching logout action clearing local storage and navigating to logout and when dispatching logout action my meta reducer clears all state as described in question

Comment: ok, do you use effects? You should move the code for localStorage.clear() and the navigation in an effect that triggers on the Logout action. After the navigation I assume "login" access the store but then a reducer is involved and your undefined state will be initialized again. I'm on my way out but if needed I'll post an example when I get back.

Comment: The way you've set up your metareducer should work so I am guessing the problem is with the implementation of the reducers (do they return a default state when the input state is undefined?) or with your subscription management in the component. As long as you setup your subscription using `this.sub = store.select(state.some.data).subscribe(...)` and have a `this.sub.unsubscribe()` in `ngOnDestroy` you should be fine. Btw you should look into effects but they don't really relate to this problem. Does this help?

Comment: Another idea, maybe your initial state (the default state) isn't complete. In that case you'll get exceptions like the one you describe. The default state needs to be usable at all times as you can't really guarantee the order of things (in this case, you probably get an update before ngOnDestroy is called). Oh well. Hope it works out.

Comment: non of them worked for me I have moved my clear storage and navigation logic to effect but not working `@Effect()
  logout$ = this.actions$.ofType(fromAuthActions.LOGOUT).pipe(
    map(() => {
      localStorage.clear();
      return new fromAppStore.Go({
        path: ['/login']
      });
    })
  );`